# Attempting to stream Twitter Timeline with Tweepy but always get unfiltered JSON

Tags: python, json, twitter, timeline, tweepy

I'm working on a python app to stream Twitter using Tweepy. Whenever I try to stream the timeline I get a block of red JSON.

I've checked online extensively and everything I try yields the same results.

```
def main():
    SCREEN_NAME = '****'
    ckey = "****"
    csecret = "****"
    atoken = "****"
    asecret = "****"

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    mainMenu(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api)    
def mainMenu(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api):
        print("Welcome to the PyTwit app!")
        option=int(input("Please select 1 for home timeline, 2 for tweet, 3 for search. "))
        if option==1:
            tweetStream(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api)
        elif option ==2:
            postTweet(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,api)
        elif option ==3:
            search()
        else:
            print("Invalid entry, please try again.")
            mainMenu(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api)
def tweetStream(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api):
    SCREEN_NAME = 'Jen_B_Mart'
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    stream = api.home_timeline(creen_name = SCREEN_NAME)
    decoded = json.dumps(stream, sort_keys=True)
    print"(%s) %s" % (decoded["created_at"], decoded["text"])

    print("\n\n")
    mainMenu(ckey,csecret,atoken,asecret,auth,api)
main()
```

Comment: You forgot to close the quotes on `csecret`

Comment: Thanks. I guess I accidentally deleted it when I pasted the code but I fixed it.

Comment: can you put on the question what you're getting as a response and what you expect?

Comment: Look at `api.home_timeline(creen_name = SCREEN_NAME)`... I'm not sure `creen_name` is a legit parameter